# Re-use existing browser session

Tags: selenium

When testing web apps there's quite often a scenario where you do lots of stuff and then something breaks: 
e.g. you have typo in your xpath, a timing issue with (e.g. jQuery not finished) or something else. When this happens you have to start from the beginning but it would be great if i could continue from the point where the TC broke
Is there some process to start the same..?

Comment: No. Learn to test your locators in the dev console. It will save you a LOT of time, especially if you write long running scripts.

Comment: Another alternative is to use a debugger and put in a breakpoint where you expect something to go wrong. But as JeffC said, that wouldn't be necessary if you tested your locators first. And keep your tests small.